# Accessing runtime-created tables with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

We have an application that creates new tables at runtime, but always with the same table schema. The only thing that varies from one of these tables to the next is the table name.  Is it possible to access these tables using Entity Framework, specifying which table to access by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Entity Framework is not designed for DDL, it's an ORM tool for data access.  You would want to use a simple ADO.NET query to create/drop the table.
2. Creating and dropping tables for every user session will make your log file grow very big very fast.  I would consider carefully the reasons you think this is necessary.  If the data is temporary, why not save the Session ID in each row and truncate the table on a daily basis?

UPDATE:

No, not really.  The Entity Data Model is not dynamic, it's a static XML document that describes the structure of the database.  If you want to interact with a table with a dynamic name, you're going to have to stick to "classic" ADO.NET.

Comment: 1) That's pretty much what I expected to hear. 2) I'm told there are compelling reasons for this, but in any case it's out of my control.  Also, our application is designed for pretty small set of concurrent users.

Comment: I thought my question was too broad, so I rewrote it.  Sorry about making your answer a bit off target now.

Answer (score 1):

With Linq to SQL I guess it would be possible with a stored procedure taking the table Name as a parameter.
A nice post about SP in L2SQL: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

I don't know if that feature exists in EF.

Comment: That's not a bad thought, and it would definitely work with EF.  However, we're trying to avoid stored procedures for the sake of database portability.  Our product is designed to be customer-hosted, and we support 4 different DBs.  Stored procedures make this more difficult.